# Fatal crash when navigating between nav graphs with navigation drawer ( jetpack compose )

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a root navigation with root, auth-graph, and main-graph. The main graph has a bottom navigation and a navigation drawer. I have NavHostController in the root navigation. When I pass this navcontroller to the auth-graph everything works fine However, when I pass this navController to the main-graph I receive the following error: `"ViewModelStore should be set before setGraph call" exception` (which I now know each nav host must have its own controller). I fix this issue by using a separate nav host controller for the main graph however this issue I am currently facing is trying to logout which involves navigating back to the auth-graph, in which case I get the following error `Compose Runtime internal error. Unexpected or incorrect use of the Compose internal runtime API`

```
Root Graph



AnimatedNavHost(navController = controller, route = ROOT, startDestination = START_UP) {
        composable(route = START_UP){
            LoadingScreen()
        }

        composable(route = MAIN_HUB) {
            MainHub(navController = controller,destinations = destinations)
        }

        authHub(controller = controller, destinations = destinations)
}
```

```
Auth Graph

fun NavGraphBuilder.authHub(controller: NavHostController, destinations: Destinations) {

    val home = destinations.find<HomeEntry>()
    val welcome = destinations.find<WelcomeEntry>()
    val create = destinations.find<CreateEntry>()
    val login = destinations.find<LoginEntry>()
    val onboarding = destinations.find<OnboardingEntry>()

    navigation(route = AUTH_HUB, startDestination = welcome.destination()){
        composable(home.destination()){
            controller.navigate(MAIN_HUB)
        }

        with(welcome) {
            composable(controller, destinations)
        }

        with(login) {
            navigation(controller, destinations)
        }

        with(create) {
            navigation(controller, destinations)
        }

        with(onboarding) {
            navigation(controller, destinations)
        }
    }
}
```

```
Main Graph

fun NavGraphBuilder.homeNavigation(navController: NavHostController, destinations: Destinations) {

    val account = destinations.find<AccountEntry>()
    val settings = destinations.find<SettingsEntry>()
    val analysis = destinations.find<AnalysisEntry>()
    val home = destinations.find<HomeEntry>()
    val healthPlanner = destinations.find<HealthPlannerEntry>()
    val workoutPlanner = destinations.find<WorkoutPlannerEntry>()
    val profile = destinations.find<ProfileEntry>()
    val training = destinations.find<TrainingEntry>()
    val workoutTracking = destinations.find<WorkoutTrackingEntry>()
    val healthTracking = destinations.find<HealthTrackingEntry>()
    val logout = destinations.find<LogoutEntry>()

    navigation(route = MAIN_HUB, startDestination = home.destination()){

        with(home){
            composable(navController, destinations)
        }

        with(logout){
            composable(navController, destinations)
        }
    }
}
```

```
Navigation Drawer
ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModularDrawSheet(
                items,
                scope,
                drawerState
            ) {
                navController.navigate(it.route)
                bottomNavState = it.route == "home"
            }
        }
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = { TopAppBar(title = {}, navigationIcon = { NavDrawerIcon(scope, drawerState) }) },
            bottomBar = {
                AnimatedVisibility(visible = bottomNavState) {
                    NavBar(navController = navController)
                }

            }
        )
        { padding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)) {
                home(navController = navController, destinations)
            }
        }
    }
```

It is currently working if pass in the root nav host controller and use for the logout composable and use the current nav host controller for all other content. however, the animation back to login is choppy, and passing in the root nav host controller doesn't seem like a good solution.

Is there a way to handle navigating back to the auth graph from the main-graph